# Problem with v-for, Where it is iterating multiple times in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <div
        v-for="accordion in accordions"
        :key="accordion.title"
        class="line"
        :class="{
          green: accordion.text === 'AllaboutVue',
          red: accordion.textwo === 'hi',
          pink: accordion.text === 'Allaboutwebpack',
        }"
      >
        <BaseAccordian>
          <template v-slot:title>{{ item.val }}</template>
          <template v-slot:content>
            <div>{{ accordion.text }}</div>
            <div>{{ accordion.textwo }}</div>
          </template>
        </BaseAccordian>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Issue with v-for, Where it is iterating multiple times. As you can see in the above codesandbox.

Where I am looping data with v-for, As every item which coming from v-for iterating multiple times. So how to avoid that, and what's problem with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `v-for="item in items"` in `v-for="accordion in accordions"`

Example:

```
<div
  v-for="accordion in accordions"
  :key="accordion.title"
  class="line"
  :class="{
    green: accordion.text === 'AllaboutVue',
    red: accordion.textwo === 'hi',
    pink: accordion.text === 'Allaboutwebpack',
  }"
>
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <BaseAccordian>
      <template v-slot:title>{{ item.val }}</template>
      <template v-slot:content>
        <div>{{ accordion.text }}</div>
        <div>{{ accordion.textwo }}</div>
      </template>
    </BaseAccordian>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-change-dynaic-forked-51wmq)

Also you have typo in `dataone`:

```
{
    id: 8,
    val: "7",
    kk: "gg",
    status: "notok"
  },
```

`val` must be `"8"`

Comment: @Sundar, you can show `{{ item.kk }}` instead of `{{ accordion.text }}`, it's not a problem

Comment: @Sundar, (showing multiple color), because each  `accordion.textwo` = `hi`, just check css and you will understand why this behavior

Comment: Updated https://codesandbox.io/s/data-change-dynaic-forked-51wmq

Comment: Just remove `{{ accordion.title }}`

Comment: Just add condition `<div v-if="accordion.title === 'Vue'">` updated demo

Comment: If i undestand you correct, you want something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-minsky-e1zzs ?

Comment: See demo, i changed css